# R: Adding columns from two data frames of different length by a key

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

I have two data frames with the same columns. One column is a 'key'. I want to add the values of all other columns based on this key. The data frames have different key values, some overlap and others do not.

Here is an example for a simple case with only two columns that need to be added together, where I manually add the columns together:

```
library(dplyr)

# fake data
df1 <- data.frame(Time = 1:10, V1=rnorm(10), V2 = rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(Time = 5:13, V1=rnorm(9), V2 = rnorm(9))

# merge data on Time
df_join <- full_join(df1, df2, by="Time")
df_join[is.na(df_join)] <- 0

# add columns together
df_join <- df_join %>%
  mutate(V1 = V1.x + V1.y,
         V2 = V2.x + V2.y) %>%
  select(Time, V1, V2)
```

I'm sure there is a way to do this without manually adding the columns but I can't quite get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can gather/spread them to deal with all at once:

```
full_join(gather(df1, k, v, -Time), gather(df2, k, v, -Time),
          by=c("Time", "k")) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(v.x, v.y), funs(if_else(is.na(.), 0, .))) %>%
  mutate(v=v.x + v.y) %>%
  select(Time, k, v) %>%
  spread(k, v)
#    Time         V1         V2
# 1     1 -0.4108213  2.2635681
# 2     2  0.8734349  0.5203859
# 3     3  0.2322048 -2.1499689
# 4     4 -1.0893187  1.6631661
# 5     5  2.7415923  1.2145786
# 6     6  2.2640301 -0.5760655
# 7     7  0.8883223  0.9012936
# 8     8  3.8600507 -0.2658887
# 9     9 -0.5409009 -0.3971484
# 10   10  0.3518266  0.6282677
# 11   11  1.4754595 -0.2267939
# 12   12  0.1045988 -0.7126889
# 13   13 -1.1350954 -0.4815504
```

Comment: Perfect. Cheers!